# Intersection of two lists using LINQ

Tags: c#, database, linq, list, intersect

I have a User called admin who has a list of Companys.  I want to return a list of Users who have one or more of the same Companys.  I am using Linq using this query but I'm not sure why it is not working.  I don't really understand what the .Any() does but if I don't include it, the program has syntax errors.  Here is my attempt:

```
public List<User> GetUsers(User admin)
{
    return Users.Where(user=>user.Companys.Intersect(admin.Companys)).Any()).ToList();

}
```

Comment: What is the result of your attempt?

Comment: an empty list. I'm not sure how to debug the statement at all.

Comment: What type has the list `Companys`? If it's a `List<Company>` `Company` needs to override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` or implement `IEquatable<Company>`. You could also create a custom `IEqualityComparer<Company>` which you can use in the overload of `Intersect`.

Comment: Since you have added the `database` tag, I think it can help you: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb301437(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @TimSchmelter - _ needs to override `Equals`_ that depends very much on the underlying system. For Linq-to-Objects the normal reference equals should be adequate.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: not if OP wants   this to return `true`: `new Company("Google").Equals(new Company("Google"))`

Comment: @TimSchmelter .Net equals will use the memory space for the default version of equals to equals in an unknown object.

var a = new Object();
a == a (true)

var a = new Person("FOO")
var b = new Person("FOO")
a == b (false)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT:
People in the comments are taking about overriding equals for your Company object and they are correct however we might be able to do something easier. The reason you need to override equals is because .Net doesn't know how to find equality in an object you created. so you would need to program in how to let it know. It does know how to find equality in an ID most times however.

EDIT 2:
The Intersect Any is the way to go because you are want to compare a list to a list

```
public List<User> GetUsers(User admin)
{
    var adminCompanyIDs = admin.Companys.Select(c => c.ID);
    return Users.Where(user=>user.Companys.Select(c => c.ID).Intersect(adminCompanyIDs).Any()).ToList();        
}
```

So Contains will search the list to see if any single value are in the list. Because it only searches for a single value it won't work for this.

Intersect will return the intersections of the two lists. for example [1,2,3] [2,3,4] would give [2,3].

Where requires a boolean for the function evaluation.  Give me the values in my list where the function given returns true. So when you give back [2,3] it complains. Any says are there any results in the list. so [2,3].Any() returns true, satisfying the Where.

Contains doesn't return the Intersection of the list, just tells you True of False, Does the value exist

Hope that helps.

Comment: it is giving me a syntax error about wrong number of arguments

Comment: This definitely helped, but I am still getting an error about "does not take 1 argument"

Comment: Seems as though the Intersect > Any is the best way to go for checking if any values of a list are contained in the first list. Sorry I didn't have VS open when writing this answer. I hope the extra information helped!

Comment: Contains checks **one** item, not a collection of items.

Answer (score 2):

try intersecting on a unique property instead of the object

```
return Users.Where(user=>user.Companys.Select(c => c.ID).Intersect(admin.Companys.Select(a => a.id)).Any())
        .ToList();
```